# clear image array on button click

Tags: iphone

i have an array

```
 imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], 
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                            nil];
```

i want to clear this array on button click.

these are series of images on screen.

and if i press  button clearing the image should clear all the images.

How can i do it?

regards
shishir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[imageArray release];
imageArray = nil;
```

Comment: Ensure you have this linked as a UIButton!