# Under ARC, how do I release the elements in an NSArray?

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

Under standard Objective-C manual memory management, it was suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3178039/19679) that the way to release an NSArray initialized using

```
imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], 
                        [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                        nil];
```

was to use

```
[imageArray release];
imageArray = nil;
```

Given that we no longer can use `-release` under automatic reference counting, what would be the suggested way to release this NSArray under ARC?

Comment: Please give your question some actual content instead of just linking to another one and asking "how to do this using ARC"

Comment: Under ARC, can't you just set imageArray = nil; and the static analyzer will decide whether to place a release?

Comment: possible duplicate of [clear image array on button click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178039/clear-image-array-on-button-click)

Comment: @BoltClock - I believe the question can stand on its own.  It just needed a little better wording (which I've tried to supply).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the imageArray is an ivar for an object (perhaps not a safe assumption), you should use an accessor to set the array to nil; the accessor will take care of releasing the array and all of its members:

`[self setImageArray:nil];`

If you need to clean out an array with many members but keep a valid array ready in that ivar so that other methods can safely send it messages, you can use the following:

`[self setImageArray:[[NSArray alloc] init]];`

Which will replace the old array with a new, empty array.

Comment: It's a little misleading to say that you're keeping the array. You're not keeping it, you're replacing it with a new, empty array.

Comment: "If the imageArray is an ivar for an object (perhaps not a safe assumption), you should use an accessor to set the array to nil; the accessor will take care of releasing the array and all of its members" An ivar isn't the same as a property. Every property uses an instance variable, but not every instance variable uses a property. Also, under ARC, you don't need properties to get the automatic releasing. Just set the ivar to `nil` (thus: `imageArray = nil`) and the compiler will do the job. ;-)

Comment: What about an array with a scope method, i.e. created and living for the method invocations ?

Comment: @RandyMarsh, to be exact, not every property has to use an instance variable, e.g. one with custom access method.

Answer (score 19):

To use ARC you just remove your `retain` and `release` messages and that's it. So you get rid of your array like this:

```
 imageArray = nil;
```

This works and doesn't leak because under ARC the compiler automatically inserts the necessary `retain` and `release` calls.